# How to resolve "No route matches" functional test errors in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5

I've upgraded to Rails 5.  My first hurdle in getting specs to pass is a 'No route matches' error.

Please see my test and test_helper below.  Is there anything I need to add to test_helper or test.rb?  Anyone know the cause or how to resolve this?

## .....

I've been running a single test while trying to simply get a pass:

```
bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:31
```

which is the 'should get new' line in my users_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
describe UsersController do
//class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
   before do
     glenn = users(:glenn)
     sign_in(glenn)
   end

  it 'should get new' do
    get new_user_url
    value(response).must_be :success?
  end
end
```

this results in the following error.

```
Error:
UsersController#test_0002_should get new:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"http://test.host/users/new", :controller=>"users"}
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

## test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/rails'

class ActionController::TestCase
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
  fixtures :all
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess # fixture_file_upload
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and was able to get it to work, though I'm not entirely sure about the internals of why it works.

Apparently the type of spec is necessary.

What I had that resulted in similar error as above:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TimingsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET new" do
    it "renders the new template" do
      get new_timing_path
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
end
```

What I have now that works:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TimingsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET new", type: :request do
    it "renders the new template" do
      get new_timing_path
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
end
```

So it seems like the `type: request` part is essential.

Answer (score 0):

While troube-shooting this I created a new rails 5 app, installed devise and minitest-rails...and those tests are passing.  The new url style syntax is working fine inside the describe block in my controller tests.  However, in the app that pertains to this questions...the url syntax is not working inside the describe block and the fix---at least for now, was to replace the describe block with a class that inherits from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.  I have no idea, yet, why this is.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting `host` help for your case?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Session.html#method-i-host

```
host! "subdomain.example.com"
```